# Проблема с EachValidator и связью many to many в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, mvc

**Задача.** Есть 3 таблицы в базе данных: `event`, `bundle`, `event_bundle`. Таблица `event_bundle` связывает таблицы `event` и `bundle`. То есть там такие колонки: `id`, `event_id`, `bundle_id`. Получается связь many to many.

Необходимо на странице `update/create` для `event` отобразить все `bundle` через ActiveForm checkboxlist. Дать возможность выбрать `bundle`, к которым привязан текущий `event`.

**Мой код:**

**action из контроллера:**

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $model->setScenario(Event::SCENARIO_UPDATE);
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save())
    {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }
    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
        'bundleList' => ArrayHelper::map(Bundle::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
    ]);
}
```

**мой _form.php**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'description')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'is_active')->dropDownList([0 => 'No', 1 => 'Yes']) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'bundles')
    ->checkboxList($bundleList, ['separator' => '<br />']) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

**и модель (базовая, храню в common\models):**

```
class Event extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'event';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['title'], 'required'],
        [['description'], 'string'],
        [['is_active'], 'integer'],
        [['title'], 'string', 'max' => 256],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'title' => 'Title',
        'description' => 'Description',
        'is_active' => 'Is Active',
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getEventBundles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(EventBundle::className(), ['event_id' => 'id']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getOrders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::className(), ['event_id' => 'id']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getTimetables()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Timetable::className(), ['event_id' => 'id']);
}
}
```

**в backend я наследую предыдущую модель и код ее таков:**

```
class Event extends \common\models\Event
{
const SCENARIO_EDIT   = 'eventEdit';
const SCENARIO_UPDATE = 'eventUpdate';
const SCENARIO_CREATE = 'eventCreate';

private $bundles = array();

public function rules()
{
    $rules =  parent::rules();
    $rules[] = ['bundles', 'each', 'rule' => ['integer']];
    return $rules;
}

public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
    EventBundle::deleteAll(['event_id' => $this->id]);

    foreach ($this->bundles as $bundle)
    {
        $eventBundle = new EventBundle([
            'event_id' => $this->id,
            'bundle_id' => $bundle,
        ]);
        $eventBundle->save();
    }
}

public function setBundles($value)
{
    $this->bundles = $value;
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getBundles()
{
    // TODO узнать, можно ли сразу получить массив без обхода и избавиться от него
    $result = $this->hasMany(EventBundle::className(), ['event_id' => 'id'])->select(['bundle_id'])->asArray()->all();
    $bundles = [];
    foreach ($result as $item) {
        $bundles[] = $item['bundle_id'];
    }
    return $bundles;
}

public function scenarios()
{
    return [
        self::SCENARIO_EDIT   => ['title', 'is_active'],
        self::SCENARIO_UPDATE => ['title', 'description', 'is_active', 'bundles'],
        self::SCENARIO_CREATE => ['title', 'description', 'is_active', 'bundles'],
    ];
}
}
```

**Проблема.** При сохранении возникает ошибка валидации:

> Bundles must be an integer.

Я посмотрел и понял, что у меня при сохранении модели `$model->save()` начинается валидация. И Validator вызывает в классе `Event` метод `setBundles` и в `$value` почему-то передает по очереди каждый из элементов массива, который принял в `$_POST`, а не сам массив... И как я понял именно из-за этого и возникает проблема.

У меня 2 варианта:

1. Или я не знаю как работют сеттеры и геттеры в Yii.
2. Или я не знаю как работает `EachValidator`.

Прошу помочь.

Comment: Предлагаю переименовать в `private $_bundles = array();` И использовать имя отличное от геттера

Comment: заюзай эту библиотеку https://github.com/voskobovich/yii2-many-to-many-behavior

Answer (score 0):

вместо `private $bundles = array();` попробуйте `public $bundlesData = [];`
ну и в остальных местах поменять.

Ну и вместо 
`'bundleList' => ArrayHelper::map(Bundle::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),`
Я бы сделал в afterFind эту логику

```
public function afterFind(){
  parent::afterFind();
  $this->bundlesData = ArrayHelper::map($this->bundles, 'id', 'name');
}
```

В `getBundles()` должна быть связь, а не то что у Вас там сейчас